# Are SpriteBatch drawcalls culled by XNA?

Tags: matrix, xna, zooming, scale, transformation

I have a very subtle problem with XNA, specifically the SpriteBatch.
In my game I have a Camera class. It can Translate the view (obviously) and also zoom in and out.
I apply the Camera to the scene when I call the "Begin" function of my spritebatch instance (the last parameter).

The Problem: When the cameras Zoomfactor is bigger than 1.0f, the spritebatch stops drawing.
I tried to debug my scene but I couldn't find the point where it goes wrong.

I tried to just render with "Matrix.CreateScale(2.0f);" as the last parameter for "Begin".
All other parameters were null and the first "SpriteSortMode.Immediate", so no custom shader or something.
But SpriteBatch still didn't want to draw.

Then I tried to only call "DrawString" and DrawString worked flawlessly with the provided scale (2.0f).

However, through a lot of trial and error, I found out that also multiplying the ScaleMatrix with "Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, 0, -1)" somehow changed the "safe" value to 1.1f.
So all Scale values up to 1.1f worked. For everything above SpriteBatch does not render a single pixel in normal "Draw" calls. (DrawString still unaffected and working).

Why is this happening?
I did not setup any viewport or other matrices.
It appears to me that this could be some kind of strange Near/Farclipping.
But I usually only know those parameters from 3d stuff.

If anything is unclear please ask!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is near/far clipping.

Everything you draw is transformed into and then rasterised in projection space. That space runs from (-1,-1) at the bottom left of the screen, to (1,1) at the top right. But that's just the (X,Y) coordinates. In Z coordinates it goes from 0 to 1 (front to back). Anything outside this volume is clipped. (References: [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206269(v=vs.85).aspx), [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee418867(v=vs.85).aspx), [3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206341(v=vs.85).aspx).)

When you're working in 3D, the projection matrix you use will compress the Z coordinates down so that the near plane lands at 0 in projection space, and the far plane lands at 1.

When working in 2D you'd normally use `Matrix.CreateOrthographic`, which has near and far plane parameters that do exactly the same thing. It's just that `SpriteBatch` specifies its own matrix and leaves the near and far planes at 0 and 1.

The vertices of sprites in a `SpriteBatch` do, in fact, have a Z-coordinate, even though it's not normally used. It is specified by the `layerDepth` parameter. So if you set a layer depth greater than 0.5, and then scale up by 2, the Z-coordinate will be outside the valid range of 0 to 1 and won't get rendered.

(The documentation says that 0 to 1 is the valid range, but does not specify what happens when you apply a transformation matrix.)

The solution is pretty simple: Don't scale your Z-coordinate. Use a scaling matrix like:

```
Matrix.CreateScale(2f, 2f, 1f)
```

Comment: Solution works perfect. Thanks for the in-depth explanation, that was really useful!